# Jquery click one checkbox should select all checkbox within one row

Tags: jquery

I'm trying select all checkbox within one row `(tr)`. So that I'm using One query code to do this. But it's checked 2 row's checkbox.

But it's should select like this:

If I select `MON` then it's select all checkbox under this. If I select `TUE` it's should select all checkbox under this but now it's select all.

```
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="mon_morning" value="mon_morning" id="checkAll"/>&nbsp;<strong>MON</strong></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="mon_morning" value="mon_morning" class="checkItem"/>&nbsp; Morning</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="mon_afternoon" value="mon_morning" class="checkItem"/>&nbsp; Afternoon</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="mon_evening" value="mon_evening" class="checkItem"/>&nbsp; Evening</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="mon_morning" value="mon_morning" id="checkAll_1"/>&nbsp;<strong>TUE</strong></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="tue_morning" value="tue_morning" class="checkItem_1"/>&nbsp; Morning</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="tue_afternoon" value="tue_morning" class="checkItem_1"/>&nbsp; Afternoon</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="tue_evening" value="tue_evening" class="checkItem_1"/>&nbsp; Evening</td>
  </tr>

<script>
$('#checkAll, #checkAll_1').click(function () {    
    $(':checkbox.checkItem').prop('checked', this.checked);    
    $(':checkbox.checkItem_1').prop('checked', this.checked);    
 });
</script>
```

Sorry my bad English:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought would be:

```
$('td:first-child input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
    $(this)
    .closest('td')
    .siblings()
    .find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/a5uEB/).

Revised, to take account of the class-names for the `<input>` elements (that I originally missed):

```
$('td:first-child input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
    $(this)
    .closest('tr')
    .find('.checkItem').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/a5uEB/1/).

Updated to feature an automatic check-all check/uncheck, if the other `<input>` elements in the `<tr>` are checked/unchecked:

```
$('tr input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
    var cell = $(this).closest('td'),
        row = cell.parent(),
        checkItems = row.find('.checkItem');
    if (cell.is(':first-child')) {
        checkItems.prop('checked', this.checked);
    } else {
        row.find('td:first-child input')
            .prop('checked', checkItems.length === checkItems.filter(':checked').length);
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/a5uEB/3/).

References:

- [`:checked` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Comment: I'm glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#checkAll, #checkAll_1').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: I know i can do this with separate code.  But I want it within one set of code.

Answer (score 0):

Add attribute to 'Day" checkbox and use that to select the appropriate day-parts:

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="mon_morning" grp="checkItem" value="mon_morning" id="checkAll"/>&nbsp;<strong>MON</strong></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="mon_morning" value="mon_morning" class="checkItem"/>&nbsp; Morning</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="mon_afternoon" value="mon_morning" class="checkItem"/>&nbsp; Afternoon</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="mon_evening" value="mon_evening" class="checkItem"/>&nbsp; Evening</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="tue_morning" grp="checkItem_1" value="tue_morning" id="checkAll_1"/>&nbsp;<strong>TUE</strong></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="tue_morning" value="tue_morning" class="checkItem_1"/>&nbsp; Morning</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="tue_afternoon" value="tue_morning" class="checkItem_1"/>&nbsp; Afternoon</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="tue_evening" value="tue_evening" class="checkItem_1"/>&nbsp; Evening</td>
</tr>
```

Use that attribute to select the day-parts:

```
$('#checkAll, #checkAll_1').click(function () {   
  $('.' + $(this).attr("grp")).prop('checked', this.checked);    
});
```

see [fiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/wjJHc/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a class for checkAll like this:

**html**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mon_morning" value="mon_morning" class="checkAll"/>
```

and in **js**

```
$(".checkAll").on("click",
                  function(){
                      if($(this).prop("checked"))
                          $(this).parent().nextAll("td").find("input:checkbox").prop("checked",true)
                      else
                          $(this).parent().nextAll("td").find("input:checkbox").prop("checked",false)                              
                  });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6RPv/8/)